# Using Hydrogen, how do I save they python script with output included like a jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, python-2.7, atom-editor, hydrogen

I'm new to Atom and Jupyter. I've only installed Hydrogen and I'm testing on a simple script. I can make some data and, shift+Enter shows the plot inline! I'd like to save the file w/ the output blocks I see in the Atom+Hydrogen GUI. I've seen other Jupyter notebooks like this. Can I do it and how?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Pandoctools](https://github.com/kiwi0fruit/pandoctools) for this. It can export hydrogen *.py / *.md documents to any Pandoc output format or to Jupyter notebook.

For example you can [create and register](https://github.com/kiwi0fruit/pandoctools/blob/master/docs/tips.md#install-python-kernel) Jupyter kernel. For example is can be named "nn". That should be the same kernel that you selected in Atom/Hydrogen. Then add hat to the Python file, split Hydrogen to cells, provide settings and set Markdown cells (commented metadata line would export to ipynb that can be opened in [nteract](https://nteract.io/) native app):

```
"""
---
kernels-map:
  py: nn
jupyter:
  kernelspec:
    display_name: nn
    language: python
    name: nn
pandoctools:
  out: "*.pdf"
  # out: "*.ipynb"
...

# Markdown section title 1

Some **static** Markdown text.
"""


# %% {echo=False}
import IPython.display as ds
import math
import sugartex as stex


# %% {markdown}
"""
# Markdown section title 2

The quick brown Fox jumps over the lazy dog.
"""


# %%
ds.Markdown(stex.pre(f'''

Some **dynamic** Markdown text with SugarTeX formula: ˎα^˱{math.pi:1.3f}˲ˎ.
It works because of the `Markdown` display option and `sugartex` Pandoc filter.
Acually `stex.pre` is redundant here but it is needed when the text is imported
or read from somewhere instead of being written in the same document.

'''))
```

Then convert the file via pandoctools: drag and drop file to pandoctools shortcut/executable or "open with" pandoctools executable.

Also see:

- introduction article: [convenient and easily tweakable Atom+Markdown+Pandoc+Jupyter experience](https://github.com/kiwi0fruit/misc/blob/master/src/atom_jupyter_pandoc_markdown.md),
- [examples](https://github.com/kiwi0fruit/pandoctools/tree/master/examples) of input to output conversion that have cross-references!
- how to use [Pandoctools](https://github.com/kiwi0fruit/pandoctools) and it's [**CLI**](https://github.com/kiwi0fruit/pandoctools/blob/master/pandoctools/cli/README.md),
- how to use [Knitty](https://github.com/kiwi0fruit/knitty) that collects Jupyter outputs and change it's [**settings**](https://github.com/kiwi0fruit/knitty/blob/master/docs/knitty.md).